# Unable to pass javascript variable to PHP through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have searched through a couple of QA here at stackoverflow, none of solutions seemed to help. I am trying to pass `input` to my PHP file but for some reason the `input`doesn't get passed from javascript to and it  keeps on returning `undefined` on the console.

my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"go.php",
    data:{input:input},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data); //data outputs https://mp3skull.wtf/search_db.php?q=&fckh=1d41a1579f21a921d1008d90dc6246a7
    }
});
```

my php:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET['input']; //$input here is empty

$keywords= explode(" ",$input);
$link = "https://mp3skull.wtf/search_db.php?q=" . $keywords[0];

for($i = 1; $i < count($keywords); $i++){
    $link .= "+" . $keywords[$i];
}
$link .= "&fckh=1d41a1579f21a921d1008d90dc6246a7";
echo $link; //$keywords is not appended to $link
?>
```

Comment: How and where are you populating the js variable `input` ?

Comment: Are you doing anything else with `$link`? I'd think JS could handle replacing spaces with `+`s.

Comment: Make sure input is getting to the php as a value. If it's undefined, $link will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code works you probably `console.log` from outside the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

hi first you need to declare it as a variable. Second does your variable really have a value? I'll give u sample you can run your code do it something like this

```
var input = $("#input").val();

$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"go.php",
data:{input:input},
success:function(data){
    console.log(data); //data outputs https://mp3skull.wtf/search_db.php?q=&fckh=1d41a1579f21a921d1008d90dc6246a7
}
 });
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

If you have the following Html:

```
<input type="text" class="field" />
<input type="button" class="button">
```

You should use the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"go.php",
            data:{'input':$('input.field').val()},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because when you send data in "data: { input: input } " are defining the variable input with the same name. It should be like that

```
 var inputValue = $("#idInput").val();
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"go.php",
    data:{input:inputValue},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```